# Unit tests, check if function have been called

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, vue-test-utils

I need to implement a test that checks if the function has been called on the button click

```
onSave (e) {
 this.$qiwaApi.createDimension()
   .then(() => {})
   .catch(err => this.showSnackbar(err.message))}
```

I need to test the function createDimension. In my test i mocked it

```
const createComponent = () => {
    wrapper = mount(dimensions, {
      store,
      localVue,
      mocks: {
        $qiwaApi: {
          createDimension: function (e) {
            return new Promise((resolve) => { resolve({}) })
          }
        }
      },
      router
    })
  }
```

In the project, the function exported this way

```
export default $axios => ({
  createDimension (data, surveyId) {
    return $axios.post(`/lmi-admin/surveys/${surveyId}/dimension`, {
      data: {
        attributes: {
          ...data
        }
      }
    })
  }
})
```

I expect this test to work. But for some reason wrapper.qiwaApi or wrapper.createDimension return undefined

```
expect(wrapper.$qiwaApi.createDimension).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrapper doesn't provide access to your mocks that way.

You would have to hold a reference to a `jest.fn()`, and then verify the calls on that reference directly instead of trying to pull it out of the wrapper:

```js
it('calls createDimension on button click', async () => {
  const createDimension = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve())
  const wrapper = mount(dimensions, {
    mocks: {
      $qiwaApi: {
        createDimension
      }
    }
  })

  await wrapper.find('[data-testid="save"]').trigger('click')
  expect(createDimension).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

[demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vue-test-utils-verify-call-demo)